# Reproducing default plot behaviour of pandas.DataFrame.plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

As a frequent user of pandas, I often want to plot my data.

Using the `df.plot()` is very convenient, and I like the layout it gives me.

I often have the problem that when I show the generated graph to someone else, they like it, but want some tiny changes.

This often digresses into me trying to recreate the exact graph in `matplotlib`, which turns into a couple of hundred rows of code and it still does not work quite the same way as the `df.plot()`

Is there a way to get the settings for the default plotting behaviour from pandas and just ad something to the plot?

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,6],index=[15,16,17,18], columns=['values'])
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

This little piece of code makes this pretty graph:

[image]

Trying to recreate this with matplotlib turns into a few hours of digging through documentation and still not comming up with quite the right solution.

Not to mention how many lines of configuration code it is.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.bar(df.index, df['values'], 0.4, align='center')       
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax1.xaxis.set_ticklabels(["","15", "16", "17", "18"])

plt.show()
```

[image]

TLDR;
How can I easily copy the behaviour of `df.plot()` and extend it, without having to recreate everything manually?

Comment: You can just plot with pandas, access the matplotlib `Axes` object by using `ax = df.plot()` and then customize it further from there.

Comment: Or, `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); df.plot(ax=ax); ax. ...`